# Shortest distance to cover all the (N+1) points. All the N points lie on x- axis. Remaining one point lies anywhere in the coordinate plane

Tags: math, distance, coordinate-systems

Given `(N+1)` points. All the N points lie on x- axis. Remaining one point (HEAD point) lies anywhere in the coordinate plane.
Given a START point on x- axis.

Find the shortest distance to cover all the points starting from START point.We can traverse a point multiple times.

Example `N+1=4`

points on x axis
`(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)`

**HEAD Point**
`(1,1)`     //only head point can lie anywhere //Rest all on x axis

**START Point**
`(0,1)`

[image: Image only for reference]

I am looking for a method as of how to approach this problem.
Whether we should visit HEAD point first or HEAD point in between.

Comment: Let's see if I understand the problem. You want to find a path, which passes through every point at least once, and which starts at the start point. You further want the path to begin at a particular point. It does not matter when the HEAD point is in the path, the path can end at any point. You want the path which has minimum length.

Comment: Yes, I want to find the path which passes through every point at least once including HEAD, and which starts at the START point. Also it does not matter when the HEAD point is in the path. I want to know the path so as to find the distance or just the approach which will give me the path. As such it is a coding question based on mathematics. If there is no such approach the last option will be to try every possible permutaion and add distance from START to the point at beginning of permutation.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find a way using Graph Theory to simplify this problem and reduce the paths that need to be considered. If there is an elegant way to represent this problem using graphs to identify a solution, I was not able to find it. This approach becomes very inefficient as the **n** increases - the time and memory is O(2^n).

Looking at this as a tree graph, the root node would be the START point, then each of its child nodes would be the points it is connected to.

Since the START point and the rest of the points aside from the HEAD all lay on the x-axis, all non-HEAD points only need to be connected to adjacent points on the x-axis. This is because the distance of the path between any two points is the sum of the distances between any adjacent points along the path between those two points (the subset of nodes representing points on the x-axis does not need to form a complete graph). This reduces the brute force approach some.

Here's a simple example:

[image]

The upper left shows the original problem: points on the x-axis along with the START and HEAD points.

In the upper right, this has been transformed into a graph with each node representing a point from the original problem. The edges represent the paths that can be taken between points. This assumes that the START point only represents the first point in the path. Unlike the other nodes, it is only included in the path once. If that is not the case and the path can return to the START point, this would approximately double the possible paths, but the same approach can be followed.

In the bottom left, the START point, **a**, is the root of a tree graph, and each node connected to the START point is a child node. This process is repeated for each child node until either:

- A path that is obviously not optimal is identified, in which case that node can just be excluded from the graph. See the nodes in red boxes; going back and forth between the same nodes is unnecessary.
- All points are included when traversing the tree from the root to that node, producing a potential solution.

Note that when creating the tree graph, each time a node is repeated, its "potential" child nodes are the same as the first time the node was included. By "potential", I mean cases above still need to be checked, because the result might include a nonsensical path, in which case that node would not be included. It is also possible a potential solution results from the path after its child nodes are included.

The last step is to add up the distances for each of the potential solutions to determine which path is shortest.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a careful examination of the different cases.

Assume for now START (S) is on the far left, and HEAD (H) is somewhere in the middle the path maybe something like

```
                    H
                   / \
S ---- * ----*----*   * --- * ----*
```

Or it might be shorter to from H to and from the one of the other node

```
                   H
                  //
S ---- * --- * -- *----------*---*
```

If S is not at one end you might have something like

```
                    H
                   / \
* ---- * ----*----*   * --- * ----*
  --------S
```

Or even going direct from S to H on the first step

```
                    H
                   / |
* ---- * ----*----*  |
                     S
```

A full analysis of cases would be quite extensive.

Actually solving the problem, might depend on the number of nodes you have. If the number is small < 10, then compete enumeration might be possible. Just work out every possible path, eliminate the ones which are illegal, and choose the smallest. The number of paths is I think in the order of n!, so its computable for small n.

For large n you can break the problem into small segments. I think its enough just to consider a small patch with nodes either side of H and a small patch with nodes either side of S.

This is not really a solution, but a possible way to think about tackling the problem.

(To be pedantic stackoverflow.com is not the right site for this question in the stack exchange network. [Computational Science : algorithms](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) might be a better place.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun problem. First, lets try to find a brute force solution, as Poosh did.

### Observations about the Shortest Path

#### No repeated points

You are in an Euclidean geometry, thus the triangle inequality holds: For all points a,b,c, the distance d(a,b) + d(b,c) <= d(a,c). Thus, whenever you have an optimal path that contains a point that occurs more than once, you can remove one of them, which means it is not an optimal path, which leads to a contradiction and proves that your optimal path contains each point exactly once.

#### Permutations

Our problem is thus to find the permutation, lets call it M_i, of the numbers 1...n for points P1...Pn (where P0 is the fixed start point and Pn the head point, P1...Pn-1 are ordered by increasing x value) that minimizes the sum of |(P_M_i)-(P_M_(i-1))| for i from 1 to n, || being the vector length sqrt(v_x²+v_y²).

The number of permutations of a set of size n is n!. In this case we have n+1 points, so a brute force approach testing all permutations would have complexity (n+1)!, which is higher than even 2^n and definitely not practical, so we need further observations to improve this.

#### Next Steps

My next step would now be to see if there are any other sequences that can be proven to be not optimal, leading to a reduction in the number of candidates to be tested.

#### Paths of non-head points

Lets look at all paths (sequences of indices of points that don't contain a head point and that are parts of the optimal path. If we don't change the start and end point of a path, then any other transpositions have no effect on the outside environment and we can perform purely local optimizations. We can prove that those sequences must have monotonic (increasing or decreasing) x coordinate values and thus monotonic indices (as they are ordered by ascending x coordinate between indices 0 and n-1):
We are in a purely one dimensional subspace and the total distance of the path is thus equal to the sum of the absolute values of the differences in x coordinates between one such point and the next. It is clear that this sum is minimized by ordering by x coordinate in either ascending or descending order and thus ordering the indices in the same way. Note that this is true for maximal such paths as well as for all continuous "subpaths" of them.

### Wrapping it up

The only choices we have left are:

- where do we place the head node in the optimal path?
- which way do we order the two paths to the left and right?

This means we have n values for the index of the head node (1...n, 0 is fixed as the start node) and 2x2 values for sort order. So we have 4n choices which we can all calculate and pick the shortest one. One of the sort orders probably determines the other but I leave that to you.

Anyways, the complexity of this algorithm is O(4n) = **O(n)**. Because reading in the input of the problems is in O(n) and writing the output is as well, I believe that is an algorithm of optimal complexity. However, if we could reformulate the problem somewhat, so that we could read and write the input and output in some compressed form, as in only the parameters that we actually need to solve the problem, then it is possible that we could do better.

P.S.: I'm not a mathematician so I probably used wrong words for some concepts and missed the usual notation for the variables and functions. I would be glad for some expert to check this for any obvious errors.

Comment: I think in the first example, the optimal path can contain the same points multiple times; it just can't traverse more than once between any two pairs of points. I'm also thinking I just don't know enough about graph theory to simplify the problem with that approach, and there may be a specific type a graph with certain properties that would prevent the brute force approach. And if the HEAD and START points lie horizontally between the rest of the points, some points will necessarily have to be traversed multiple times. Fun but just can't think of a good representation!

Comment: Actually, now I'm wondering - there has to be some limit for the maximum number of edges - it would have to be less than or equal to the number of edges in a complete graph with **n** vertices, right? So the depth would be n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 0 = 0.5(n^2-n), so that would be the necessary depth of the tree. Unless I'm missing something in this maximum depth assumption, that would work out to polynomial time rather than exponential.

Comment: I guess you definitely wouldn't need to travel from each point to every single other point, so we know the distance of the path has to be less than the sum of the distances between every pair of points. A node would become a leaf if adding any of its child nodes would cause the distance of the path to be greater than the maximum. And the tree includes every possible path. So that would be O(n^2)... Maybe?